# Redux toolkit can I pass several payloads to the action?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Before in Redux, I can pass payloads like:

```
export const quizSetState = (answerState, results) => {
return {
    type: QUIZ_SET_STATE,
    answerState,
    results,
  };
};
case QUIZ_SET_STATE:
 return {
  ...state,
  answerState: action.answerState,
  results: action.results,
 };
```

But how to do it in Redux-toolkit

```
dispatch(quizSetState({ [answerId]: 'success' }, results));
   
quizSetState: (state, action) => {
  state.answerState = action.answerState;
  state.results = action.results;
}
```

I can't handle this and instead dispatching 2 times

```
quizSetAnswerState: (state, action) => {
   state.answerState = action.payload;
},
quizSetResultsState: (state, action) => {
   state.results = action.payload;
},

dispatch(quizSetAnswerState({ [answerId]: 'success' }));
dispatch(quizSetResultsState(results));
```

PS: I read docs and there were preapre callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

action.payload can be an object that contains the variables you want to set, you can try this:

```
quizSetState: (state, action) => {
  state.answerState = action.payload.answerState;
  state.results = action.payload.results;
}

dispatch(quizSetState({answerState: { [answerId]: 'success' }, results})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it helped, but to finish it fully you have define both objects as payload like: 

reducer
`dispatch(quizSetState({answerState: { [answerId]: 'success' }, results: results})
`
action
`quizSetState: (state, action) => {
  state.answerState = action.payload.answerState;
  state.results = action.payload.results;
}`